# Determining how a scalar field transforms considering an infinitesimal form of the Lorentz transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

Considering the infinitesimal form of the Lorentz transformation $x^a \rightarrow x^{\prime a}=\Lambda_b^a x^b = x^a+\omega^a_b x^b$ (which preserves the Minkowski metric, such that $g_{a b} x^a x^b=g_{a b} x'^a x'^b$ or $g_{\mu \nu}=g_{a b} \Lambda^a_\mu \Lambda^b_\nu$ for all$x$, and where $\Lambda^a_b=\delta^a_b+\omega^a_b$), I'm trying to derive how a scalar field $\phi(x^a)$ transforms, but I'm a bit stuck. I know I can use $\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi^{\prime}(x)=\phi\left(\Lambda^{-1} x\right)$, but how can I go from this $g_{\mu \nu}=g_{a b} \Lambda^a_\mu \Lambda^b_\nu$, to this expression: $\left(\Lambda^{-1}\right)^\mu_\nu=g^{\mu a} g_{\nu b} \Lambda^b_a$ ? It's been a while since I worked with tensors, hence the question.

Comment: You actually have brought up a lot of different issues in this paragraph. (1) $\Lambda = \delta + \omega$ is only a useful way to write a Lorentz transformation if $\omega$ is small, not for general transformations. (2) You generally don't want to use Latin letters $a, b, \cdots$ and Greek letters $\mu, \nu, \cdots$ to refer to the same thing -- it will cause you a lot of headaches when you get to more advanced physics where objects carry different kinds of indices. Instead it's better to use more Greek letters like $\rho, \sigma, \lambda, \cdots$.

Comment: (3) The equation you wrote for $\phi$, $\phi(x)\rightarrow \phi'(x)=\phi(\Lambda^{-1}x)$ **is** how $\phi$ transforms (under an "active transformation"). (4) It's important to keep track of what index on $\Lambda$ comes first or second, because $\Lambda$ is not symmetric, so you want to write $\Lambda^\mu_{\ \ \ \nu}$, never $\Lambda^\mu_\nu$. (5) For your actual question, it helps to know that you can write $g_{\mu\nu}=g_{\rho\sigma}\Lambda^{\ \ \ \rho}_\mu\Lambda^\sigma_{\ \ \ \nu}$ in matrix notation as $g=\Lambda^T g \Lambda$. Then, using $\Lambda^{-1}=\Lambda^T$ (...)

Comment: (...) you can rewrite this as $1 = g^{-1} \Lambda^T g \Lambda$, or $\Lambda^{-1} = g^{-1} \Lambda^T g$. If you write out the indices of this last expression (and are careful about where to put the indices on $\Lambda)$), it will be equivalent to what you wrote. Note that the transpose switches the order of indices, so $(\Lambda^T)^\mu_{\ \ \ \nu}=\Lambda^{\ \ \ \ \mu}_\nu$. Also note that $g^{\mu\nu}$ are the components of $g^{-1}$.

Comment: Finally, conventionally, people use the symbol $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ rather than $g_{\mu\nu}$ to refer to the Minkowski metric. It isn't a huge deal, but it can be useful to distinguish a flat metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ which transforms as a tensor under Lorentz transformations, to a general metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ which does not. (A general metric only transforms as a tensor under general coordinate transformations, a global Lorentz transformation isn't even defined, in a general manifold, once you go beyond special relativity).